# Adding a Flow type for a Redux Thunk action with a return value

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, flowtype, redux-thunk

I have a thunk action that after dispatching other actions, returns a `boolean`. I'm unsure of how to type this with Flow. This is the action:

```
export const checkAuthStatus = (): ThunkAction => async (dispatch) => {
  const token = await getFromStorage('authToken');
  const user = await getFromStorage('authUser', true);
  const promptSkipped = await getFromStorage('promptSkipped', true);

  const loggedIn = token && user;

  if (loggedIn) {
    dispatch(setLoggedIn(token, user));
    dispatch(getUserInBackground());
  }

  return promptSkipped;
};
```

The `ThunkAction` return type comes from this snippet in the [Flow docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/) where `Action` currently includes the types for all of the non-Thunk actions:

```
type GetState = () => State;
type PromiseAction = Promise<Action>;
type ThunkAction = (dispatch: Dispatch, getState: GetState) => any;
type Dispatch = (action: Action | ThunkAction | PromiseAction | Array<Action>) => any;
```

This snippet works if I were to simply call `await checkAuthStatus()`, but if I try to assign the return value e.g. `const skipped = await checkAuthStatus()` I get:

```
Cannot call await with `checkAuthStatus()` bound to `p` because  `ThunkAction` [1] is incompatible with  `Promise` [2].Flow(InferError)
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Edit**: [Here is a reproducible example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDKGAhhgQLxgDeqYYA1PAObN4AmAkgHYBcYAIzhwYeEtwA0dRjgBOcALY4MhANYBLHPnb8hIsZNQBfdNnxgAggGMM6uNzAVpAHyJ4MAGTisOPa7fsAbnRgYDAAFRJVPAcoeQUwAAsMDBwAZ15Q2EQAOjhZZmAY4HY4KzTgWTEbSo4AVwAPNDMCAHF3YjJKMAAKAEpHAD4iUnJglrAABXj1NLx-OwcqacVZvAAeBftB8dwCcMS67lUtpd72WZwyK0T+ABFL68SJMDYVUbx+dveugYph8RYXbmB5pK4YG6OXokGyLfinMCuA5HE6w+yIqYzOYI1wWWSyEhYTZo7iDP4A7hA9B4Bo4fIYMBWexpBk3PBWE51DCJToYOppKH9fjI44I-5gEhpLDcKznR4QxLkmjSJncFlgFhsLh8QTCUTiKFQEgwObBeiq9VyRTKNSabS6PUGKEYWR1PDBaQXMFPHpzTzeLU8Hqa3zcPp9D30Kp82QOK1KFQaLQcYJGD0WhnkFkAYUS7M53N5-Khkulsv6Q2V5uZDPjNqT2hLCBI6lZeY5Fi5PNG-P6ZrA0lCEUSszAo+5BBg6m4BG5ZDAaUScDqMHYggIeHx+WnzDAUHyEpSeATO7AGDgEvYa5IC5dp-PEt1+nEORVzP0ORYPTribtHEYYAAOT7nAgERsYHoTIQ7heD42pilWZ57PwgGEAAouEAD6HgAPKtK0aF3JhnAAHKAVI9BXFg8AkDoT76oYabUrS9KMjWC4wQGoaCrMsGBjqegMUqPTUEh+AoehWG4fhhHEWRLxUTRdG8Vx2pgEY4GoEAA).

I need line `30` to error as I'm trying to add a `string` to a `boolean`, but as you can see, it's throwing the above error.

Comment: Please provide more information. For reference, here is how to write a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterHall I've edited the post to add an example.